# Char addition does not have expected result in C

Tags: c, twos-complement, unsigned-char

Can someone explain me how is this at the end

```
a=?,b=?,c=-124
```

and not

```
a=?,b=?,c=132
```

This is code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char a = 'D', b='C', c='A';
  a = c + 'D';
  b = a + b + 'A';
  c = b - a;
  a = a - b + 'C';
  b = b - 68;
  printf("a=%c,b=%c,c=%d", a, b, c);
}
```

Comment: It makes little sense to add character codes to each other.

Comment: It would make more sense if you explained *why* you would expect `132`.

Comment: `char` is signed on your system, so you're getting negative numbers.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli He's expecting `132`

Comment: [Is char signed or unsigned by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2054941)

Comment: The behavior depends on your system... does it use ASCII? If so, then the char values of the ASCII values of the corresponding characters (e.g., 'A' = 65). And the results of the arithmetic depends on whether your compiler uses `signed` or `unsigned` `char`s by default.

Comment: For example  a=c+'D'  in compiler it show that a is -123. I just need someone to explain me in what way it happened.

Comment: Add `printf("a=%d, b=%d, c=%d\n", a,b,c);` after each line and check the values using `signed char` and `unsigned char` and you will understand what is going on.

Comment: To see the issue, have you tried using `int` instead of `char`? In that case, you won't get rollover. With `char a = 127, b = a + 1; printf("a=%d b=%d\n",a,b);` you'll get `a=127 b=-128` but, using `int`, you'll get: `a=127, b=128`

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your C implementation has a signed eight-bit `char`, likely uses ASCII, and, when converting an out-of-range value to a signed integer type, wraps modulo 2<sup>*w*</sup>, where *w* is the width of (number of bits in) the type. These are all implementation-defined; they may differ in other C implementations, with certain constraints.

`char a = 'D', b='C', c='A';` initializes `a` to 68, `b` to 67, and `c` to 65.

`a = c + 'D';` assigns 65 + 68 = 133 to `a`. Since 133 does not fit in `char`, it wraps to 133 − 256 = −123.

`b = a + b + 'A';` assigns −123 + 67 + 65 = 9 to `b`.

`c = b - a;` assigns 9 − −123 = 132 to `c`. This wraps to 132 − 256 = −124.

`a = a - b + 'C';` assigns −123 − 9 + 67 = −65 to `a`.

`b = b - 68;` assigns 9 − 68 = −59 to `b`.

`printf("a=%c,b=%c,c=%d", a, b, c);` prints `a=?,b=?,c=-124` because `a` and `b` are codes for abnormal characters and the value of `c` is −124.

Answer (score 2):

It appears on your system that `char` is signed. With ASCII, `'D'`, `'C'` and `'A'` are the same as the integers `68`, `67`, and `65` respectively.

Add `68` to `65` and you get `133`. The binary representation of `133` is `10000101`. Notice that the most significant bit is `1`. As you're using signed chars, twos complement comes into play, and the result is actually `-123`.

Remember that a signed `char` can hold values ranging from `-128` to `127`, rather than `0` to `255`.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem your compiler treats `char` as `signed char`, so:

`a = 'D', b='C', c='A'`

`a = c + 'D'`  =  `'A' + 'D'`  =  `65 + 68`  =  `133`

but since `a` is a `signed char`, it becomes `-123` (133-256)

`b = a + b + 'A'`  =  `-123 + 'C' + 'A'`  =  `-123 + 67 + 65`  =  `9`

`c = b - a`  =  `9 - -123`  =  `9 + 123`  =  `132`

`a = a - b + 'C'`  =  `-123 - 9 + 66`  =  `-66`

`b = b - 68`  =  `9 - 68`  =  `-59``

So at the end, `a = -66`, `b = -59`, and `c = 132`